# Weird behavior of Try-Catch in a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, transactions, try-catch

I have a stored procedure where I need to cast to a type, but do not know if the cast will succeed. In an imperative language, I would use some sort of `TryCast` pattern. I figured that this would be equivalent in T-SQL:

```
begin try
   select cast(@someValue as SomeType)
end try begin catch end catch
```

On the surface, it does appear to be equivalent. If `@SomeTypeVar` is uninitialized and the cast fails, I get `NULL` to work with; the correct value if the cast succeeds.

I used this same code in a stored procedure, but that yields an error: `Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 20. The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.` Some research led me to other questions on Stack Overflow and this table of times when `try-catch` fails in T-SQL:

> TRY…CATCH constructs do not trap the following conditions:
>
> - Warnings or informational messages that have a severity of 10 or
>     lower.
> - Errors that have a severity of 20 or higher that stop the SQL
>     Server Database Engine task processing for the session. If an error
>     occurs that has severity of 20 or higher and the database connection
>     is not disrupted, TRY…CATCH will handle the error.
> - Attentions, such as
>     client-interrupt requests or broken client connections.
> - When the
>     session is ended by a system administrator by using the KILL
>     statement.
>
> The following types of errors are not handled by a CATCH
>   block when they occur at the same level of execution as the TRY…CATCH
>   construct:
>
> - Compile errors, such as syntax errors, that prevent a batch from
>     running.
> - Errors that occur during statement-level recompilation, such
>     as object name resolution errors that occur after compilation because
>     of deferred name resolution.
>
> These errors are returned to the level
>   that ran the batch, stored procedure, or trigger.

At first, I thought I fell into the statement-level recompilation bucket (as my error level is 16) until I tried to bisect the problem. The minimal reproduction is as follows:

```
create procedure failsInTransactions
as
begin
    begin try
      select cast(@someValue as SomeType)
    end try begin catch end catch
end
```

and the calling code:

```
begin tran
  exec failsInTransactions
commit
```

This yields the error I discussed above. However, I remembered that if a stored procedure doesn't have any parameters, you can call it without exec. This:

```
begin tran
  failsInTransactions
commit
```

succeeds with `Command(s) completed successfully.` Further experimentation led me to another error with level 16:

```
begin try
  select 1/0
end try begin catch end catch
```

which works in both cases, producing no rows of output.

I have two questions:

1. Why is there different behavior calling the procedure with and without `exec`?
2. Why does another error of the same error level proceed after the catch?

Comment: Canonical ref": http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling_2005.html

Comment: I've been to both of those pages and they don't really seem to help much in this scenario.

Comment: I had 2 choices: post the links (which you don't mention in original question) in the hope they might be helpful, or do nothing.

Comment: You can't call a procedure without `exec` because the procedure has no parameters - you can call it without `exec` if - and *only* if - it's the first statement in the batch. `begin tran / foo / commit` begins a transaction called `foo` and then commits it - if you have a stored procedure called `foo`, it isn't getting called, and that's why you're not getting an exception. If you used semi-colons ([like you should](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons))...

Comment: ...and schema prefix ([like you should](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix.aspx)), or even just basic debugging 101 at the beginning of your procedure (like `print 'hello world';`), you wouldn't have gotten this far believing your procedure was working when in fact it wasn't even getting called. And please, always use `EXEC` when calling stored procedures, in spite of what you "remember"...

Comment: Anyway, there is no "weird" behavior going on here, at least in terms of differing behavior with and without `exec`. Both calls to the stored procedure would fail if you were actually making the calls in both cases (try `exec sp_executesql N'failsInTransactions';` if you don't believe me...).

Comment: I did not know about named transactions. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EXECUTE keyword is optional only if it is the first statement in the batch.  It is not related to parameters and is required in all other contexts.  Microsoft inherited this odd behavior from the Sybase code base as well as other many lax T-SQL parsing rules.  I suggest you follow a strict T-SQL coding style to avoid gotchas.

The code below runs without error because it is not executing a proc at all.  Since there are no semicolon statement terminators, the stored procedure name becomes part of the BEGIN TRAN statement and is interpreted as a transaction name.

```
begin tran
  failsInTransactions
commit
```

You will get the expected syntax error during compilation if you add statement terminators and this will lead you down the path to specify EXEC.

```
begin tran;
  EXEC failsInTransactions;
commit;
```

Be aware that not using statement terminators is deprecated so I suggest you get in the habit of specifying them.  See https://www.dbdelta.com/always-use-semicolon-statement-terminators/.